# Update data on client side by server push

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm using wcf. I have a simple method in web service that retrieves some string data from database and returns that string data to client.

```
public string getSomeStringfromDatabase(){
   string s ="";
   //retrieving from database logic into string s
   return s;
}
```

Really simple method, nothing special..

Now I would like to learn how to use this method to update that string from database on my clients side by "server push" style or how it is called.

Can someone give me a simple example?

I read some topics on internet pushing vs polling, but couldn't find simple enough code to understand it.

Can you give an example of push with web service method and polling too if it's not too much?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at SignalR. Its a server Push Framework which uses HTML5 WWeb Socket beneath. I have created chat server here using SignalR.

https://github.com/omkarpanhalkar/AjaxChatRoom

Comment: Didn't hear about it. I have to see. Can you tell me where in your code exactly did you use it? thank you

Comment: WCF can do it fine, [here is a good article explaining how](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx) ([Part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/19/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-a-wcf-duplex-service-part-ii.aspx)).

Comment: I've found polling duplex binding with silverlight to not be very reliable. It kept faulting on us and we missed callbacks because of it.

Comment: Calling server method from javascript https://github.com/omkarpanhalkar/AjaxChatRoom/blob/master/ChatRoom/ChatRoom.Web/Views/Home/ChatRoom.cshtml